# javascript emulating jQuery syntax

Tags: javascript

In jQuery, the '$' alias serves many purposes. It acts like a function here:

```
$('#someid')
```

but you can also make it act as a object:

```
$.attr('id', 'hello');
```

How can I make a function that has this property (being able to be called as itself and as an object with methods)?

**EDIT:**

Also, sometimes you can chain like so:

```
$('id').html('<span>Hello</span>);
```

How do I extend the object to accompany this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Functions *are* objects in JavaScript, so you can add a property to a function the same way you would for any other object.

```
function $(id) {
    // blah blah
}

$.attr = function (id, attr) {
    // blah blah
}
```

Comment: Just leaving this here for reference: this is defined in the [ECMAScript specification 4.3.28](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-function)

Comment: @frozen: Dr_Derp's answer explains that aspect of things nicely :)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is open-source and the following lines are taken directly from their github repo in order to give some more clarification to the previous answer:

```
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {

        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
    },

    // Support: Android <=4.0 only
    // Make sure we trim BOM and NBSP
    rtrim = /^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g,

    // Matches dashed string for camelizing
    rmsPrefix = /^-ms-/,
    rdashAlpha = /-([a-z])/g,

    // Used by jQuery.camelCase as callback to replace()
    fcamelCase = function( all, letter ) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    };

jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {

    // The current version of jQuery being used
    jquery: version,

    constructor: jQuery,

    // The default length of a jQuery object is 0
    length: 0,

    toArray: function() {
        return slice.call( this );
    },
```

It was taken from the middle, so it is safe to assume that jQuery as an object was declared earlier in the code `var jQuery =...` and also keep in mind that `$` just a shorthand for `jQuery` and they are attached to `window` global object. You may take time to look into the awesome opensource itself to get clearer idea: https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Answer (score 2):

The question of how to make the "function" act like an object was answered correctly by Joe, so I'll not bother to answer that part again.

In order to be able to chain function calls (which is what is happening in the second part of your question), the functions you call need to return an object. It would look something like this:

```
var func = function() {
    this.func2 = function() {

        return this;
    };

    return this;
};

// then the following code will work:
func().func2();
```

To illustrate how it works, it's equivalent to these statements:

```
var funcObject = func();
funcObject.func2();
```

Also important to note that jQuery is probably not returning `this`, but rather a wrapped DOM object that can have various functions like `attr` called on it. But it's basically the same concept:

```
$ = function(id) {
    var wrappedDomObject = getWrappedDomObject(id);

    return wrappedDomObject;
}

// somewhere in jquery

function getWrappedDomObject(id) {
    // some code to get the object

    wrappedObject.attr = function(id, value) {
        // some code here

        return this;
    }

    return wrappedObject;
}
```

Because the `$` function is returning an object, you can immediately call the `attr` function on whatever it's returning, and if necessary, can continue to chain function calls on that object because of `return this`.

Please bear in mind I don't actually know for sure if this is how jQuery works, this is just a potential implementation to illustrate the concept.